# Expect Tcl script - Error passing quoted argument using spawn

Tags: tcl, rsync, expect

I just wrote a very simple Expect script for wrapping around rsync, but it seems to be giving me trouble.  Basically, I am automating the SSH login prompt called from rsync.  I also have to pass arguments through rsync to SSH so it doesn't do the host key checking.  I am well aware of SSH authentication keys and ssh-keygen, but I have good reasons for doing things this way so no lectures on passing passwords on the command-line.

## Script

---

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f

if {$argc != 5} {
  puts "usage: remoteCopy {remotehost, username, password, localfile, remoteloc}"
  exit 1
}

set remotehost [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set localfile [lindex $argv 3]
set remoteloc [lindex $argv 4]

set timeout -1

spawn rsync -e \"ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no\" $localfile $username@$remotehost:$remoteloc
expect "Password"; send "$password\r"
```

Here is the complete output from the script:

## Output

---

```
avoelker@localhost  $ ./remoteFileCopy.tcl remotehost remoteuser remotepass ~/localfile /tmp/
spawn rsync -e "ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /localhost/home/avoelker/localfile remoteuser@remotehost:/tmp/
rsync: Failed to exec "ssh: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(83)
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(434)
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "$password\r""
    (file "./remoteFileCopy.tcl" line 17)
avoelker@localhost  $
```

It appears to me that rsync is trying to execute `"ssh` instead of just `ssh`, however, copying and pasting the first line of output from Expect's stdout (`rsync -e "ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /localhost/home/avoelker/localfile remoteuser@remotehost:/tmp/`) directly into the shell works perfectly fine, so I know it isn't a problem with rsync.

When I remove the -e argument entirely from the `spawn rsync` line, the Expect script executes without errors, but I would have to add in host key checking to the script, which I do not want to do.

Does someone more experienced with Expect/Tcl know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop your backslashes.  The `spawn` line should just say:

```
spawn rsync -e "ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $localfile $username@$remotehost:$remoteloc
```

After all, you don't want `rsync` to see a command with a quote in it, do you?

Comment: Wow, I could have swore that was the first thing I tried.  In any case, it works now!  Thank you

Comment: AbeVoelker, I recommend that you also review your spelling.  Depending on the configuration of your host, for example, "expect Password" might work *most* of the time, while "expect Password:" gives more deterministic correct behavior.  Even worse, that prompt might need to change from target machine to target machine.